# "Operation not permitted" for root under Mojave

Tags: root, macos-mojave

Very frustrating: I cannot mv, rm etc as a root on MAC OS 10.14.

There seems to be a solution here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/332673/what-and-how-does-macos-mojave-implement-to-restrict-applications-access-to-pers#new-answer?s=48cff4034161476583b318b961feb7d1

but it does nothing in my case:
I just added Terminal to the list of apps that have full access to "Full Disk Access" (I don't see "Application Data" field in Settings), –– still I simply cannot remove a file under /usr/bin , it says " Operation not permitted":

```
root@VKMBP4:/usr/bin$ whoami
root
root@VKMBP4:/usr/bin$ pwd
/usr/bin
root@VKMBP4:/usr/bin$ mv python was-python 
mv: rename python to was-python: Operation not permitted
root@VKMBP4:/usr/bin$ rm python 
override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel restricted,compressed for python? y
rm: python: Operation not permitted
```

Any suggestions how to fix it (beside uninstalling Mojave)?
Thanks!

[Here is a Screenshot: Settings / Security & Privacy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO4yN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that you can be logged-in as root, and the Mac OS X CLI will still require you to type `sudo` for privileged operations.  By the way, you should probably be using `sudo` from a regular admin user, rather than root.

Comment: Probably you are saying I logged in into my MAC as a root: no. You are wrong. 
For starters, there is no such account on the computer.   
I of course used sudo to make myself root. 
Overall, please don't teach me UNIX, as I've been using it for the last 20 years.
Better help me deal with stupid Apple "extensions" that create the problem described in my OP, –  if you can.

Comment: To clarify further: I think this behavior is specific to the latest MAC OS. I haven't seen anything like that for years : root used to be root, 

    rm -rf / 

worked with no additional questions.

Comment: @VK18 I have seen this behavior on previous versions of the OS, with certain operations starting maybe 5 years ago.  My answer did not imply anything about which user you had logged-in as graphically, but your CLI clearly shows that you were logged-in as root there.  Please don't insert words or intention into answers that simply weren't there to begin with.  Additionally, I've also been using Unix for the last 20 years, am a former Apple employee, and maintained a certification on  the Mac OS for over 8 years.  If the answer solved your question, please don't get defensive about it.

Comment: miles_b: I specifically used root account to make my story shorter; for the same reason -- to avoid any questions like "did you try sudo "... -- I added the line "whoami " in the description. However if it pleases you I can use sudo with my personal account, to the same effect of course: 

     `vk@MBP4:/usr/bin$ pwd`

     `/usr/bin`

     `vk@MBP4:/usr/bin$ sudo rm python `

     `Password:`

     `override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel restricted,compressed for python? y `

     `rm: python: Operation not permitted`

Comment: This may solve the issue for you then: http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/